# Por que inflar um Layout no Fragments ao invés de configurar um já pronto? Ex: setContentView(R.layout.activity_exemplo)

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragment, android-activity

Eu estou aprendendo sobre Android e gostaria de entender melhor como funciona essa parte do sistema.

Ao invés de inflar um layout, não seria mais simples fazer como ao criar uma Activity, como por exemplo, sobrescrever o método onCreate e configurar um layout XML?

Exemplo:

```
public class SampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState ) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample);
    }
}
```

Aqui está um parte do código de um aplicativo exemplo que pode ser clonado do github:
https://github.com/udacity/ud839_ViewPager_Example/tree/quiz

```
public class FridayFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_friday, container, false);
    }
}
```

Por que inflar é necessário? Qual a vantagem dele?
Obrigado por quaisquer esclarecimentos.

Answer (score 2):

O `LayoutInflater` é a classe responsável por criar uma `View` a partir de um arquivo XML, portanto, você precisa dele para instanciar e acessar uma `View`.

Nos fragments, como o `onCreateView()` exige uma `View` de retorno, você tem que usar o `LayoutInflater` para criar e retornar tal `View`.

Já na Activity, não precisar criar a `View` usando um `LayoutInflater` pois o método `setContentView()` já faz isso internamente, portanto ele é apenas um meio prático de criar e atribuir uma `View` a uma Activity. Se você olhar a implementação do método `setContentView()` da Activity, vai ver que ele também usa um `LayoutInflater`.

```
@Override
    public void setContentView(int resId) {
        ensureSubDecor();
        ViewGroup contentParent = (ViewGroup) mSubDecor.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        contentParent.removeAllViews();

        // Cria a View baseada no id do layout passado e atribui a Activity
        LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(resId, contentParent);
        mOriginalWindowCallback.onContentChanged();
    }
```

Comment: Não me parece que isso responda à pergunta. Ela seria uma óptima edição da pergunta de forma a dar contexto. Ela o que faz é justificar a pergunta quando diz: "Já na Activity, não precisa criar a View usando um LayoutInflater pois o método setContentView() já faz isso internamente ...". Assim sendo, então, por que o Fragment não tem também um método setContentView()?

Comment: Não consigo pensar em uma resposta melhor, afinal, temos que levar em conta que a API foi definida desse jeito. No fragment, vc pode definir todos os parametros do inflater, por isso precisamos chamá-lo no `onCreateView()`. Já na activity, esses parâmetros são pré-definidos, e portanto o método `setContentView()` simplifica essa chamada. Portanto, acho que tudo não passa de um meio de facilitar o programador.

Comment: Você me ajudou a entender melhor como esse processo funciona. E eu realmente te agradeço muito pela ajuda. Mas ainda resta uma dúvida. Por que não usar simplesmente o setContentView() no Fragment? Talvez realmente seja como as coisas foram implementadas. Mas mesmo sendo assim, a equipe de desenvolvimento do Android sempre tenta agilizar e simplificar ao máximo as coisas para os desenvolvedores. Por que não existiria essa simplificação? Por causa que o conteúdo pode ser variável como uma viewPager usando um adapter?

Comment: No começo é meio complicado msm de entender, mas os fragments tbm funcionam como BEANs na memoria, sua instancia depois de aberta pode ser reaproveitada,  diferente da Activity, que é descartada e tbm pode ser configurada para subir mais de uma instancia sua na memoria, e outra coisa que é muito eficiente é os listeners que podem ser aplicados aos fragments, uma activity não pode receber um listener porque para cada activity o sistema cria um contexto, ou seja, o sistema que gerencia sua abertura, em relação as views, eu acredito que o fragmento use o FragmentManager para encadear toda as view

Comment: Quando o FragmentManage encadeia todas as views, quando aquele fragment é descartado todas as views ligadas a ele devem ser submetidas ao GarbageCollector, e para isso todos objetos devem ser desligados do context principal que na maioria dos casos é a Activity